# Syntax Error OledbException delete statement

Tags: vb.net, oledbcommand

I can't fugure out what my syntax error is here. Anyone spot it? Or am I going about this all wrong?

```
Dim myCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("delete * from Team where intPlayerNo='" & txtUniformNo.Text & "'_ strFirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "'_ strLastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "'_ strParentName='" & txtParent.Text & "'_ strAddress='" & txtAddress.Text & "'_ strCity='" & txtCity.Text & "'_ strState='" & txtState.Text & "'_ strZipCode='" & txtZip.Text & "'_ strPhone='" & txtPhone.Text & "'_ intAge='" & txtAge.Text & "'", myConnection)
```

Comment: Wrong SQL syntax (DELETE FROM...) and not using SQL Parameters.  Also possibly doing some data type conversions in the SQL

Comment: What is the database?

Comment: @Steve: Without parameterised queries, _compromised_. ;)

Comment: ALSO DB tables usually have something called a *Primary Key* which uniquely identifies each record so that you do not have to specify a dozen fields to delete one record.  One typo in a textbox and your SQL fails.  ALSO, there are a lot of underscores there that are in the wrong place no matter whether they are part of the column name or are supposed to be line continuation characters

Comment: Access. When I tried to delete using only the primary key, I got an error telling me there were "missing parameters" in my statement.

Comment: My question is related to the `DELETE *` that while is not a correct SQL DELETE statement is nonetheless accepted if the database is MS-Access. Thus the syntax error stems from the WHERE statement and the missing AND/OR between conditions. Parameterized query while of uttermost importance is secondary in relation to the Syntax Error

Comment: @RamziMuasher what is then your primary key?

Comment: do you really have columns named `strFirstName` and `intAge`??

Answer (score 2):

A delete statement is `Delete From Team Where...`

You would be best advised to use Parameterized Queries to avoid [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) Attacks

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong because you have multiple WHERE conditions but you don't use the correct AND/OR to connect the conditions together. Of course the DELETE * FROM table syntax is accepted only by MS-ACCESS, but the correct SQL syntax is DELETE FROM (without the *) and is accepted also by Access so it is better to use the standard.

Said that you need to use a parameterized query in your command and not a string concatenation

```
Dim cmdText = "DELETE FROM Team " & _
              "WHERE intPlayerNo = @playerNo AND " & _
              "strFirstName = @firstName AND " & _ 
              ".... and so on with the other fields "
Dim myCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(cmdText, myConnection)
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@playerNo", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtUniformNo.Text
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@firstName", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text 
... continue with the other parameters required by the WHERE statement
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Using parameters will keep your code safe from Sql Injection and avoid syntax errors if some of your textbox values contains a single quote.

Keep in mind that if your table has a primary key, then your WHERE could simply reduced to only the `PrimaryKeyFieldName = @Value`